# Insert function dosen't insert

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, nodes

Ive starting learning C# with a background of c/c++.  I am creating a simple BST but my insert function wont work. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I get this kind of error when not passing by reference in c/c++.  Since I created a two classes Node and BST, shouldn't they be passed by reference? Ive worked on this problem for a couple of hours and tried to change my code but with  no luck.

```
    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.right = null;
        this.left = null;
    }

    public Node Left
    {
        get { return left; }
        set { left = value; }
    }

    public Node Right
    {
        get { return right; }
        set { right = value; }
    }

    public int Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }


}

class BST
{
    private Node root;

    public BST()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public Node Root
    {
        get { return root; }
        set { root = value; }
    }

    public void Insert(int data)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node(data);

        }
        else
        {
            InsertHelper(root, data);

        }
    }

    public void InsertHelper( Node root, int data)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node(data);
            //return root;
        }

        if (root.Data > data)
        {
             InsertHelper(root.Left, data);
        }

        if (root.Data < data)
        {
             InsertHelper(root.Right, data);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `C#` is so way different from `C/C++`, as of your question: look at your `InsertHelper` - it actually never **insert** data (there is just no code to insert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a new node to the argument pointer instead of original one. `Insert` should be:

```
  public void Insert(int data)
    {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new Node(data);

        }
        else
        {
            root = InsertHelper(root, data);

        }
    }
```

and `InsertHelper` should be:

```
public Node InsertHelper( Node root, int data)
    {
        if (root == null)

            return new Node(data);



        if (root.Data > data)
        {
             root.Left = InsertHelper(root.Left, data);
        }

        if (root.Data < data)
        {
             root.Right = InsertHelper(root.Right, data);
        }

        return root;

    }
```

In fact you don't even need  `Insert` since  `InsertHelper` already deals with root being null

Main method for testing:

```
public static void Main()
    {


        BST bst = new BST();


        bst.Insert(5);
        bst.Insert(6);
        bst.Insert(4);
        bst.Insert(7);
        bst.Insert(3);

        Console.WriteLine(bst.Root.Data + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(bst.Root.Left.Data + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(bst.Root.Right.Data + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(bst.Root.Left.Left.Data + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(bst.Root.Right.Right.Data + " ");


    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help.  So we need to reassign root every time we add in a new node?

Comment: @Alex yes if you want to use recursion. If you look closer then you would see that it is easier and more intuitive to implement it iteratively

Comment: I made the edits as shown above.  It looks like it only works when the BST is initially empty, but after the first input the others arent added.  It shows left and right empty